# django celeryd and celery beat

Tags: python, django, celery

I am going through celery and the thing I havent understood is celeryd and celery beat.

What is the difference between them.

Lets say my system sends hundreds of message everysecond. What should I use celeryd or celery beat.

Where exactly I should use celeryd and celery beat. 
What is difference between celeryd and celery beat.

Answer (score 0):

[celerybeat](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) schedules recurring tasks.

celeryd is the daemon(s) that processing the tasks that are scheduled.

In most situations you use both together.